# Customize categories Fluxstore WooCommerce app

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I am working on fluxstore WooCommerce app on Android Studio
So I want to change categories and add my own category icons.

(FROM SOURCE CODE because the Flutter inspector is taking too much time to load I waits the debuggingprocess to finish like an hour!)

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to improve your question, in order to let others better understand the exact problem.

Answer (score 2):

go to `lib/config/config_X.json` (X is the language)
Under the `HorizonLayout`, you can change the categories and the icon; ie:

```
 {
    "category": Category ID (u can get from the url: th tagID),
    "image": "the url or the path to your local icon",
    "colors": [
        "#00796b",
        "#00796b"
    ],
    "originalColor": false
},
```